# Parse html table data and a href values using DOMXPath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I have a table with 3 columns where each of the columns could contain a link or data like this one:

```
<tr><td><a href='link1'>value1</a></td><td><a href='link2'>value2</a></td><td><a href='link3'>value3</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href='link4'>value4</a></td><td>value5</td><td>value6</td></tr>
<tr><td>value7</td><td><a href='link8'>value8</a></td><td>value9</td></tr>
<tr><td>value10</td><td>value11</td><td><a href='link12'>value12</a></td></tr>
<tr><td>value13</td><td>value14</td><td>value15</td></tr>
```

I am able to get the data for each cell of the table using the following code:

```
$data = file_get_contents('pathtomyfile');
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$rows = $xpath->query('//tr');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        foreach ($cols as $col) {
            echo $col->nodeValue;
        }
        echo "\n";
}
```

I am trying to output the table in a different format and am wondering how I can get the value of the href in addition to the value of the table cell for the cells where a link exists.  For example, for the first table cell I'd like to get "link1" and "value1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could check inside the inner loop (the one that iterates each cols) whether a link exists inside it (since some of them don't have it):

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    foreach ($cols as $col) {
        echo 'value = ' . $col->nodeValue;
        if($xpath->evaluate('count(./a)', $col) > 0) { // check if an anchor exists
            echo ' | link = ' . $xpath->evaluate('string(./a/@href)', $col); // if there is, then echo the href value
        }
        echo '<br/>';

    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IMypFB)